# Swift, iOS 9.3.2 xCode 7.3: How to debug application not seeing GPX file airdropped in CS193 Trax application

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to duplicate CS193 Trax Swift application where GPX file is airdropped to IOS device and Trax application sees it.

Problem is that Trax application does not see file and I think I have set everything up properly.

I updated info.plist to permit GPX file with:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GPX File</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>edu.stanford.cs193p.gpx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>GPX file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>edu.stanford.cs193p.gpx</string>
        <key>UTTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>gpx</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I also added (because I have had problems with this before):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I have verified in the apps info view that Document types is displaying GPX and imported UTIs is GPX.

Application is a copy of Pauls Trax demo app which only contains an application delegate call to:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool
{
    print ("url = \(url)")
    return true
}
```

Airdropping vacation.gpx which Mac sees as a GPX file displays message on iPhone:

AirDrop
..mac.. would like to share a file that requires an app from the App store.  It shows GPX icon below.

e.g.  it is trying to transfer the file as a GPX file but it doesn't know that my app can process it.

How do I debug?
I set a breakpoint in the only function I have in my app and it is never called.
DOn't know what else to look at.

Comment: I started over.  Re-entered everything.  Changed edu.stanford.cs193p.gpx to the bundle name.gpx  of my application and it is now working.
Still curious about how to debug the air drop to application seeing the file when it is not working properly?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to your question?

Comment: No, I never received an answer